# Difference between "Server Error '/' Application" and "Server Error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone explain to me the difference between these 2 errors that I' getting on my project?
[image]
and
[image]

I'm trying to create a custom 404 error page for which I created an Error Control and a view and added this to my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

This catches the error fine for the first one but not the second one.
I have a route set up as such

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So, if I do something like /Home/Login (Login doesn't exist for Home) then the first error occurs which is caught by the error. But if I do something like /Home/Index/1/Test (Test doesn't exist for Home) then I get the second error which is not caught.

Comment: The first screenshot indicates that the request was handled by the ASP.NET framework, whereas the second one was handled by IIS directly. Generally IIS will handle things which don't map to an MVC route

Comment: @ADyson is there a way for me to catch both the errors to display a custom error page?

Comment: you could implement a custom HTTP module and inject that into your pipeline, to handle requests not normally picked up by .NET. I'm pretty sure I saw an article about it once. Or you could just change IIS's custom error pages.

Comment: @ADyson that helps a lot thanks